# Change Chrome toolbar color

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, colors, themes, toolbar

I want to change the color of the Chrome UI to black/white/grey.

I've already changed the OS colors (using win8.1 x64) in the registry. Everything seems to works good so far. However Chrome doesn't take the OS colors for the tabs, the bookmarks buttons toolbar (I would also like to change the bookmark text color to white, so I can see whats there) and the "toolbar". Well just look at this: [image: picture]. I want to change the red area to black.

I know this can be done by editing *.css configs in "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome". But so far I had no luck.

BTW: I dont want to use the custom theme creator, because Chrome won't show a as Win8 style windows, but typical chrome windows style like in the picture shown. (Look at the minimize, maximize and close buttons and you will see what I mean.)

Please test your solution, because with the introduction of Win8+ and Google Chrome 32+ solution found on the web are mostly obsolete.

Thanks!

Comment: [hope this answers your] http://superuser.com/questions/831742/how-do-you-change-chromes-background-color/831765?noredirect=1#comment1092644_831765

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the official Google Chrome creator? (made by Google)

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/my-chrome-theme/oehpjpccmlcalbenfhnacjeocbjdonic