# How do you change Chrome's background color?

Tags: google-chrome

I've been looking for a way to dial down reddit's white background late at night. I ended up using Control Freak (which is very cool) with my own custom styles. [It works perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGs6F.jpg).

Except when it loads a new page it still [defaults to white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zPxF.jpg) for a couple seconds before loading my custom styles (which show up in "user agent stylesheet" in dev tools)

Is there any way to prevent the screen from flashing bright white, like it does, before the user agent stylesheet is loaded?

Comment: Re-activated extension (valid as of February 2020), offered by 'claire', does exactly that.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-colors/ageghplgcapnfpdhapeemolbmfccclke?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below links to a plugin which helps to change the background colour as per user needs, hope this helps.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-colors/ageghplgcapnfpdhapeemolbmfccclke

Once in after installing the plugin go to the plugin preferences and modify the colour you want as background.

Comment: note: This do not prevent the screen from flashing bright white when open a new tab.

Comment: Incidentally, incredibly difficult to find this one in the store. Nothing comes up when looking for the 'background color' or even 'color change'. A very obscure, hidden extension.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small extension to change text/background color for chrome browser.

With mouse dragging, page color will change in real-time. So you can adjust and adjust ... until you feel satisfied.

Here is the online installation link from chrome web store.

[Babu Color](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/babu-color/dkabogmdcebincpnhjkblipnceehimch)

It is pretty simple to use... no need any instructions.